# Сортировка знаков по имени

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, знаки

Пройдя в список знаков своего аккаунта на ruSO <kbd>Профиль</kbd> → <kbd>Активность</kbd> → <kbd>Знаки</kbd> → <kbd>Имя</kbd> заметил, что сортировка по имени работает непонятно как. Позже догадался, что скорее всего сортирует не по русским названиям знаков, а, похоже, по соответствующим английским.

Comment: По адресу ссылки как раз хорошо видно, что именно по англоязычным названиям идет сортировка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо за сообщение об ошибке.

Точно - мы сортировали по английским названиям. Я исправил этот код, так что теперь будем сортировать по переведенным именам.